# Grails: nested command objects

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-validation, command-objects

In my grails app I have an outer command object that contains a list of other command objects:

```
public class OuterCommand {

    List<InnerCommand> innerCommands = ListUtils.lazyList([], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(InnerCommand))
}

class InnerCommand {
    String code
    Long id
    String value

    static constraints = {
        code(nullable: false, blank: false)
        value(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
}
```

The rather unusual instantiation of `innerCommands` is based on [this advice](http://stateyourbizness.blogspot.com/2009/02/binding-to-collection-fields-on-command.html). However, I find that if I call `validate()` on an instance of `OuterCommand`, the validation does not seem to validate the contained instances of `InnerCommand`.

Is it possible to nest command objects and have the entire graph of command objects validated when `validate()` is called on the outermost object?

Answer (score 9):

I got this working by following these steps:

Make the inner command object validatable since it is not getting instantiated like a normal command object. There are two ways to do this, with the `@org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.Validateable` annotation, or with the grails config parameter `grails.validateable.classes`

Adding a custom validator for innerCommands to OuterCommand

```
static constraints = {
    innerCommands(validator: {val, obj ->
        // 'attributes.validation.failed' is the key for the message that will
        // be shown if validation of innerCommands fails
        return val.every { it.validate() } ?: ['attributes.validation.failed'] 
    })
}
```

Comment: See http://old.nabble.com/validating-nested-command-objects-td26714921.html#a26715507 for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Domain Objects in a [Command](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.1.10%20Command%20Objects) or nested Commands get validated by default, you would have to write [a validator](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) that loops through the innerCommands and validates them all.

```
static constraints = {
    innerCommands(validator:{val,obj ->
        //validate and merge errors from each innerCommand
    })
}
```

You'll probably have to handle the Errors object and merge it all the results together, but its not too difficult.